# Detectron2: Diverged Training. Predicted boxes or scores contain Inf/NaN

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, object-detection, detectron

I am training a custom Document Analysis model.
Approach that I have used is by fine-tuning PublayNet FastRCNN model on my custom documents, which were manually annotated.

Following is the code snippet of where I am adding configuration and starting the training. However, I am getting 'Predicted boxes or scores contain Inf/NaN.' error.

I am doing this training on google colab and on a100GPU.

```
cfg = get_cfg()

config_name = "/content/faster_rcnn_R_50_FPN_3x_config.yml"
# cfg.merge_from_file(model_zoo.get_config_file(config_name))
cfg.merge_from_file(config_name)
add_vit_config(cfg)
# cfg.merge_from_file("/content/unilm/dit/object_detection/publaynet_configs/cascade/cascade_dit_base.yaml")



cfg.DATASETS.TRAIN = (Data_Resister_training)

if split_mode == "all_train":
    cfg.DATASETS.TEST = ()
else:
    cfg.DATASETS.TEST = (Data_Resister_valid)
    cfg.TEST.EVAL_PERIOD = 1000

cfg.DATALOADER.NUM_WORKERS = 0
#cfg.MODEL.WEIGHTS = model_zoo.get_checkpoint_url(config_name)
# cfg.MODEL.WEIGHTS="/content/model_final.pth"
cfg.MODEL.WEIGHTS = "publaynet_dit-b_cascade.pth"

cfg.SOLVER.IMS_PER_BATCH = 2
cfg.SOLVER.BASE_LR = 0.000025

cfg.SOLVER.WARMUP_ITERS = 10
cfg.SOLVER.MAX_ITER = 10000 #adjust up if val mAP is still rising, adjust down if overfit
cfg.SOLVER.STEPS = (500, 1000) # must be less than  MAX_ITER
cfg.SOLVER.GAMMA = 0.05

cfg.SOLVER.CHECKPOINT_PERIOD = 1000  # Small value=Frequent save need a lot of storage.
cfg.MODEL.ROI_HEADS.BATCH_SIZE_PER_IMAGE = 4
cfg.MODEL.ROI_HEADS.NUM_CLASSES = len(thing_classes)


os.makedirs(cfg.OUTPUT_DIR, exist_ok=True)


#Training using custom trainer defined above
trainer = AugTrainer(cfg)
#trainer = DefaultTrainer(cfg)
trainer.resume_or_load(resume=False)
trainer.train()
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
FloatingPointError: Predicted boxes or scores contain Inf/NaN. Training has diverged.
[09/21 12:01:24 d2.engine.hooks]: Overall training speed: 2 iterations in 0:00:01 (0.8316 s / it)
[09/21 12:01:24 d2.engine.hooks]: Total training time: 0:00:01 (0:00:00 on hooks)
[09/21 12:01:24 d2.utils.events]:  eta: 1:43:45  iter: 4  total_loss: 3.063e+04  loss_cls: 1.735e+04  loss_box_reg: 1.223e+04  loss_rpn_cls: 603  loss_rpn_loc: 513.4    time: 0.6229  last_time: 0.7432  data_time: 0.3190  last_data_time: 0.4346   lr: 7.5175e-06  max_mem: 13548M
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FloatingPointError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-68-49109c90768f> in <cell line: 44>()
     42 #trainer = DefaultTrainer(cfg)
     43 trainer.resume_or_load(resume=False)
---> 44 trainer.train()

9 frames
/content/detectron2/detectron2/modeling/proposal_generator/proposal_utils.py in find_top_rpn_proposals(proposals, pred_objectness_logits, image_sizes, nms_thresh, pre_nms_topk, post_nms_topk, min_box_size, training)
    106         if not valid_mask.all():
    107             if training:
--> 108                 raise FloatingPointError(
    109                     "Predicted boxes or scores contain Inf/NaN. Training has diverged."
    110                 )

FloatingPointError: Predicted boxes or scores contain Inf/NaN. Training has diverged.
```

I have tried to lower the learning rate and batch size. However, this still persists.

Kindly suggest what could be causing this.

Note: when I use what-I-think is a small model like faster_rcnn_R_50_FPN_3x, the training works fine. But with publaynet_dit-b_cascade.pth and mask_rcnn_X_101_32x8d_FPN_3x_model_final.pth, I get this same error.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue when I had a dataset split into 95% training and 5% testing. After that, I changed the train and test split to 80% and 20%, respectively. It worked for me.

or

```
SOLVER.AMP.ENABLED: false
```

or

Try with lower Learning rate

The above steps worked in different models. It depends on configurations only.

Comment: I will try this and update here.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing same Devanshi using the layout parser model weights for fine tuning on the custom datasets, however using the above provided solutions, the training ran smoothly ,but due to very small value of learning rate weights are not updating ,so not getting predictions, please reply if you have resolved this issue.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35595550)